# Android JsonObject -- I do not know what to do

Tags: android, json, if-statement, try-catch, android-volley

I can not use the data from the method. I do not know why. Where did the mistake?
I have the following json:

`{"code":"1","status":"Basarili","login":"OK","kullanici":"1"}`

```
JSONObject veri_json;
try {
    veri_json = new JSONObject(response); 
    try {
        String code,status,login,kullanici;
        code = veri_json.getString("code").toString();
        status = veri_json.getString("status").toString();
        login = veri_json.getString("login").toString();
        kullanici = veri_json.getString("kullanici").toString();

        if(code=="1") {
            etKullanici.setText(status);
        }

    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Debugger note:

> code="1" login="OK" status="Basarili" kullanici="1"

but doesn't work

```
if(code=="1") {
    etKullanici.setText(status);
}
```

I am sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Did you even try to search "How to compare strings in Java" on Google/Bing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONObject veri_json;
                                try {
                                    veri_json = new JSONObject(response);

```
                                try {
                                    String code,status,login,kullanici;
                                    code = veri_json.getString("code");
                                    status = veri_json.getString("status");
                                    login = veri_json.getString("login");
                                    kullanici = veri_json.getString("kullanici");


                                    if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                        etKullanici.setText(status);
                                    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

in above code i have to remove toString while u get object data. You have to tried above code it works like charm

Answer (score 2):

Your variable "code" is a string. You need to check the value not the reference. Change it to:

```
if (code.equals("1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You must compare the String with

```
String.equals()
```

Like:

```
if (code.equals("1")) {...}
```

code == "1" tests for reference equality (so it will never return true because "1" is the same as new String("1"), which isn't the same object as code.